# DataGrid does not update dataprovider on ItemEditEnd

Tags: apache-flex

In the following code, click a cell, change the text, then press tab and edit the next cell.

Only after moving to the third cell with another tab press does the first cell update.

Posting code here doesn't work well, so you can see it here:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/794073

Answer (score 4):

myDatagrid.executeBindings(false) does the trick.